# Copying Data from One Sheet to Another Workbook, but with some out of bounds errors

Tags: excel, vba, copy, worksheet

My code where I copy from one worksheet to another doesn't appear to be working.

I have tried messing around with the ranges but it didn't seem to work.

```
Workbooks("Copy of Sales Report_063019(002).xlsx").Worksheets("EBR 
 RANKING").Range("A1:O134").Copy _
 Workbooks("Copy of 
 ProspectAndSalesReportAll_123118_FINAL(2).xlsm").Worksheets("EBR 
 Ranking").Range("A1")
```

A lot of subscript out of range errors.

Comment: That means you either don't have a workbook with one of those names open, or those workbooks might not have sheets with those names.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but you'll typically avoid these kinds of errors if you break out each object into an intermediate variable. You're not gaining anything at all by "stacking" all of the references into one long line. In fact, you're forcing Excel to (re-)evaluate it each and every time. The bonus is that your code becomes much clearer.

As an example:

```
Dim firstSalesWB As Workbook
Dim firstSalesWS As Worksheet
Dim firstSalesData As Range
Set firstSalesWB = Application.Workbooks("Copy of Sales Report_063019(002).xlsx")
Set firstSalesWS = firstSalesWB.Sheets("EBR Ranking")
Set firstSalesData = firstSalesWS.Range("A1:O134")

Dim allSalesWB As Workbook
Dim allSalesWS As Worksheet
Dim allSalesData As Range
Set allSalesWB = Application.Workbooks("Copy of ProspectAndSalesReportAll_123118_FINAL(2).xlsm")
Set allSalesWS = allSalesWB.Sheets("EBR Ranking")
Set allSalesData = allSalesWS.Range("A1")

firstSalesData.Copy Destination:=allSalesData
```

Now when you get those kinds of errors, it's much easier to track down what the problem is -- in your case it's probably either a missing or mis-spelled workbook name or worksheet name as @BigBen mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

1)do you have both worksheets open? If not, you should open both, or if you don't want to do that, you'll need to put the full filepath so that VBA knows were to find the files.

2) you mention copying the worksheet, but what your code is doing is copying the contents of a sheet to another. Does the EBR Ranking sheet exist in the other sheet? If not, here is a snippet to add one.

```
    With Workbooks("Copy of ProspectAndSalesReportAll_123118_FINAL(2).xlsm")
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "EBR Ranking"
    End With
```